# Match similar kind of words from two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays.

```
Array1 = ['cat','dog','elephant','pig'] 
Array2 = ['cat','scat','pig','spig','bat'].
```

I need an object that contains key as the values of `Array1` and values to be the similar words that are similar to the key. I tried using `filter` and `indexOf` but it didn't seem to work

Expected Result:

```
{
  cat: ['cat','scat'],
  dog: [],
  pig: ['pig','spig'] 
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: why is the result wrapped in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the first array and take this values as key for the result object and filter the second array by looking if the values includes the key.

```js
var array1 = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'pig'],
    array2 = ['cat', 'scat', 'pig', 'spig', 'bat'],
    result = array1.reduce((r, k) => {
        r[k] = array2.filter(v => v.includes(k));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through `Array1` and find similar items in `Array2` using `indexOf`.

```
var result = {};
Array1.forEach(function(item1) {
    result[item1] = Array2.filter(function(item2) { return item2.indexOf(item1) > -1; });
});
```